# Trouble converting 02FEB22:00:00:00 to yyyymmddhhmmss in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to convert a variable with this format 02FEB22:00:00:00
[image: This is the format from proc contents]

to yyyymmddhhmmss. I have tried it several different ways and can't seem to get it right. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show what you've tried, what does your format statement look like?

Comment: This is how I am trying to do it: date=datepart(input(org, anydtdtm.));
format date date9.;
datetime=dhms(date,0,0,0);

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? In SAS a format is just instructions for how to print  values as text.  Do you want to define a format that will display datetime values as the 14 digit string in your question? Or do you want to create a character variable that contains the digit string already? Or do you want something else?

Answer (score 1):

Datetime variables just contain the number of seconds since 1960. There is no need to **convert** the variable if you want to display it with a different format.

You could create a custom format that will display the current numeric variable as that 14 digit string using a picture format:

```
proc format ;
  picture ymdhms (default=14)
    low-high = '%Y%0m%0d%0H%0M%0S' (datatype=datetime)
  ;
run;
```

And then just use that new format to display the current variable.

```
proc print data=have;
  format dtvar ymdhms. ;
run;
```

If you wanted to **convert**  it to a character variable that contains that 14 digit string you could just remove the T from the string created by the B8601DT15. format.

```
 data want;
   set have;
   length charvar $14;
   charvar=compress(put(dtvar,b8601dt15.),'T');
 run;
```